# Batch, unattended args in for loop

Tags: batch-file, for-loop

I used to work with a batch that loop to a folder and all subfolder and move all files found in another place.

A made modifications to this batch and now, the main loop is not working anymore.

```
set "arg1=%~1"
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
cd /d D:\!arg1!
set /a count=0
for /r %%i in (*.*) do (
...
)
```

Run

```
myBatch test
```

And got a `%i was unattended`

The strangest part is that I did not change this part of code

Comment: Are you sure the error is `was unattended`  *?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a composed name as argument use doublequote in the `CD`:

```
set "arg1=%~1"
cd /d "D:\%arg1%"

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set /a count=0
for /r %%i in (*.*) do (
...
)
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing I see that will cause a problem is if you pass the name of a folder that has ! in the folder name. Change

```
cd /d D:\!arg1!
```

to

```
cd /d D:\%arg1%
```

You don't need to delay expansion of that line because it is not in a FOR loop or a parenthesized block of code. In fact you do not need to setlocal enabledelayedexpansion at all for the code you have shown... of course it may be required for the code that is not shown.

Also, be sure to quote the argument (folder name) when you invoke the bat file in case there are spaces in the folder name.

If none of this fixes your problem, can we see more of the code? At least any  sections of code that contain %%i

Comment: The code will not corrupt name with `!` because arg1 is defined before delayed expansion is enabled.